# What’s the difference between in and into?

Tags: grammar, difference

What I have gotten from a website: http://languagelearningbase.com/10827/whats-difference-between-worlds-into-when-each-one-questions
However, what would I say if I were to write:

-He placed the sweet (in/into) the box.

-He was born (in/into) a rich family.

Comment: If you used _put_, either 'He put the sweet in the box' or 'he put the sweet into the box' would be acceptable. I think _in_ works better with _placed_, because it emphasises the position of the sweet in the box rather than the movement. As for the second example, the idiomatic expression is 'born into' a family.

Comment: @KateBunting does within work for the sentence to?

Comment: This definition of [within](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within) gives some examples of how the word is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is a literal use, about space, then *into* may be used when something moves from outside the space to inside it. But English speakers often don't bother with the extra syllable when it is clear without it; so

> He placed the sweet in/into the box

are both grammatical and normal.

However, *born into (a family)* is an idiom.

Comment: So, ‘born into’ is a fixed phrase and cannot be changed. 
And… for the 1st sentence either option is alright for the blank?